# $P(T_{1}<T_{2})=\frac{\omega_{1}}{\omega_{1}+\omega_{2}}$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, exponential-distribution

Supposing that $ T_{1} $ and $T_{2}$ are independent and exponentially distributed, with parameters $\omega_{1} $ and $\omega_{2}$ respectively. Then,

$$P(T_{1}<T_{2})=\frac{\omega_{1}}{\omega_{1}+\omega_{2}}$$

I have recently been looking into exponential and gamma distributions and came across this statement, but am unsure on how to prove it. I was thinking of using the memory-less property. 
$$P(T>t+s|T>s)=P(T>t)$$
Would this be a correct way to start?

Comment: I think it's easiest to observe $P(T_1 < T_2) = E[P(T_1 < T_2 | T_2 = t)]$ and compute the latter term.

Answer (score 2):

Compute the following integral.
$$
\begin{align}
P(T_1<T_2)&=\int_{0}^\infty \int_{0}^y \omega_1e^{-w_1x}\omega_2e^{-w_2y}\, dx\, dy\\
\end{align}
$$